# Naming Aggregate variable(s) in data.table by reference in R

Tags: r, reference, data.table, aggregate, naming

I would like to know if it's possible to name an aggregate variable by a dynamic reference at the time of aggregation in data.table.
Please note that I know I can rename the variable after aggregation by reference and that is not what I'm asking here!

Let's say I've got a data.table DT with three variables v1, v2, and v3.

```
> DT
  var1     var2    var3
1: 1        1       A
2: 3        0       A
3: 2        2       B
4: 1        0       A
5: 0        2       C
```

I would like to dynamically name the aggregate variable, based on the names stored in a vector OR a string variable

```
var_string <- c('agg_var1', 'agg_var2')
# the following doesn't work
DT_agg <- DT[, .( (var_string[1]) = sum(v1 + v2)), by = .( (var_string[2]) = var3)]

#this is the output I want
> DT_agg
   agg_var2   agg_var1
1:    A          6
2:    B          4
3:    C          2
```

The code above doesn't work. it gives me error of the sort:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "DT_agg <- DT[, .( (var_string[1]) = sum(v1 + v2)), by = .( (var_string[2]) = var3)="
```

I'm only interested to know if it's possible to do this at the same time as aggregation, rather than renaming the columns afterwards, which i know how to do already.

Comment: maybe `DT[, setNames(list(sum(var1+var2)), var_string[1]), by=setNames(list(var3), var_string[2])]` ? but may I ask why not rename after aggregation?

Comment: that solves my problem

Comment: and also `DT[, setnames(data.table(sum(var1+var2)), "V1", var_string[1]), by=setnames(data.table(var3), var_string[2])]`

Comment: works without "V1" as well

Comment: An interface for doing this is planned: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2655 However, I think it will be like `.(..var_string1 = x)` without the `[1]` and `[2]` allowed... not sure. @chinsoon Yeah, better to rename after aggregation `setnames(DT[whatever], my_names)`. If you have verbose=TRUE on, it will warn about slowness from named columns with `by=`. I think it might also be in the faq